# If $\Phi$ denote the cdf of the normal distribution, how can we compute the maximum of $x\mapsto2x^2\Phi\left(-\frac{cx}2\right)$?

Tags: optimization, normal-distribution, maxima-minima

Let $$\Phi(x):=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-\frac{t^2}2}\:{\rm d}t\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R$$ and $$f(x):=2x^2\Phi\left(-\frac{cx}2\right)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R$$ for some $c>0$.

> How can we compute the maximum of $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ (at least approximately)?

A theoretical derivation of the maximum seems to be complicated. So, what can we do?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think that it has no maximum. That's why I wrote "at least approximately". It is claimed [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/theory7.pdf) in Corollary 1.2 that $f$ is maximized (to two decimal places) at $x=2.38/c$.

Comment: There *is* a maximum (as $f(x)>0$ when $x\in(0,\infty)$, and $f(0)=f(+\infty)=0$). It can be computed numerically any way you like. The "$2.38$" is $$2.3812024966855406162567710764673636250134924764861305182542838\ldots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Phi(x):=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-\frac{t^2}2}\,dt=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$
$$f(x)=2x^2\Phi\left(-\frac{cx}2\right)=x^2 \left(1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{c x}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$

Let $\frac{c x}{2 \sqrt{2}}=y$ to make
$$f(y)=\frac{8 }{c^2}y^2 (1-\text{erf}(y))$$ So, we need to find the extremum of
$$g(y)=y^2 (1-\text{erf}(y))\implies g'(y)=2 y \left(\text{erfc}(y)-\frac{e^{-y^2} y}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)=0$$ that is to say the root of the transcendental equation
$$\text{erfc}(y)-\frac{e^{-y^2} y}{\sqrt{\pi }}=0$$

Graphing, we can see that the solution is close to $y=1$. Using Taylor expansion, we have
$$\text{erfc}(y)-\frac{e^{-y^2} y}{\sqrt{\pi }}=\left(\text{erfc}(1)-\frac{1}{e \sqrt{\pi }}\right)-\frac{y-1}{e \sqrt{\pi
   }}+\frac{3 (y-1)^2}{e \sqrt{\pi }}+O\left((y-1)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, solving the quadratic in $(y-1)$ gives, as an *estimate*,
$$y=\frac{1}{6} \left(7-\sqrt{13-12 e \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfc}(1)}\right)\approx 0.837293$$ making, as an *estimate*,
$$x=\frac{\sqrt{2} \left(7-\sqrt{13-12 e \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfc}(1)}\right)}{3 c}\approx \frac{2.36822}{c}$$

If we want to polish the root, let us use Newton method for the zero of function
$$h(y)=\text{erfc}(y)-\frac{e^{-y^2} y}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$
$$h'(y)=\frac{e^{-y^2} \left(2 y^2-3\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$ Starting with our fist estimate, the iterates will then be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & y_n \\
 0 & 0.8372929290 \\
 1 & 0.8418425951 \\
 2 & 0.8418822134 \\
 3 & 0.8418822164
\end{array}
\right)$$ which leads to the solution
$$x=\frac{2.3812024967}{c}$$ as already given by metamorphy in comments.